# Runing python script in NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python script :

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import time

continue_reading = True

# Welcome message
print "Launching..."
print "Press Ctrl-C to stop."


while continue_reading:
     print "Message inside loop"
     time.sleep(2)
```

If I launch this script with python Test.py it's OK :

```
Launching...
Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Message inside loop
Message inside loop
```

But if I use the python-shell module with NodeJS to run my Test.py inside a NodeJS app it not OK just because of :

```
time.sleep(2)
```

If I suppress it's work !

Something wrong with blocking thread in python and NodeJS ?

EDIT : 
Here the app.js

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('myFolder/myScript.py');

// sends a message to the Python script via stdin 
//pyshell.send('hello');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log(message);
});

pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: How are you launching it with node.js?

Comment: Can you post contents of app.js?

Comment: There is nothing special. I added the content in first post

Comment: did you check with Node.js Child Process.?